# Livefyre Sidenotes Annotation doesn't work on dynamically added text

Tags: livefyre

I have a page with text and I add livefyre sidenotes. I get the little icon at the end of each paragraph plus if I highlight text, a menu appears allowing me to comment or post the highlighted text to Facebook or Twitter.

I then add more text to the web page. I call sidenotes update selectors and the little icon at the end of each paragraph appears. However, when I highlight text, the menu does not appear.

The selector name is the same on the original text and the new text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I discovered that I need to create a new Sidenotes object and that each Sidenotes object needs a unique selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I need to create a new Sidenotes object and that each Sidenotes object needs a unique selector.